# How to retrieve text from UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I'm calling a `UIAlertView` with the `PlainTextView` style, and I'm trying to work out how I can get access to whatever the user entered in the text view before they clicked OK.

I'm using `willDismissWithButtonIndex` and the `alertView` doesn't seem to have any properties like text, or anything.

How can I get at it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Get the text field with

```
UITextField *textfield =  [alertView textFieldAtIndex: 0];
```

In your delegate method.
Refer to the documentation for further information.

Edit march 2015 due to many views the swift equivalent :

```
let textfield = alertView.textFieldAtIndex(0)
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, sorry, but what do you mean "in your delegate method" ?? I'm a n00b

Answer (score 3):

> UITextField *textfield =  [alertView textFieldAtIndex: 0];

Use this in uialertview delegate

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   UITextField *textfield =  [alert_name textFieldAtIndex: 0];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use its method:

```
- (UITextField *)textFieldAtIndex:(NSInteger)textFieldIndex
```

For index 0.